# Google Drive Api File.LIst issue with Time range query

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

When i am using Google drive API query for documents  its returning 0 items even though documents in between that range are present. I am facing this issue with time range only. I have written query below. Can anyone help me out with this..

mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' AND trashed=false AND 'me' in owners AND modifiedTime>='2018-11-16T14:00:00' AND modifiedTime<='2018-11-16T15:59:59'

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, I think that `mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' AND trashed=false AND 'me' in owners` is correct. But about `modifiedTime>='2018-11-16T14:00:00' AND modifiedTime<='2018-11-11T5:59:59'`, in this case, the files "after `2018-11-16T14:00:00`" AND "before `2018-11-11T5:59:59`" are trying to be retrieved. So the result becomes `{"files": []}`.

#### Pattern 1:

For `modifiedTime`, if you want to retrieve files from `2018-11-11T5:59:59` to `2018-11-16T14:00:00`, how about this query?

```
mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' AND trashed=false AND 'me' in owners AND modifiedTime<='2018-11-16T14:00:00' AND modifiedTime>='2018-11-11T5:59:59'
```

#### Pattern 2:

For `modifiedTime`, if you want to retrieve files of "before `2018-11-11T5:59:59`" and "after `2018-11-16T14:00:00`", how about this query?

```
mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' AND trashed=false AND 'me' in owners AND (modifiedTime>='2018-11-16T14:00:00' OR modifiedTime<='2018-11-11T5:59:59')
```

#### Note:

- In your query, `2018-11-115:59:59` of `modifiedTime<='2018-11-115:59:59` is wrong. But if `2018-11-115:59:59` is used, the query error occurs. So I supposes that you are using the correct value in your actual script.

#### Reference:

- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.